Changing the collation of an existing Microsoft SQL Azure database without using a bacpac or being offline
As the question above states I need to change the collation from SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8.
I've been able to do the bacpac method solution that comes up through searching for a test 8g db. However, we have a 500g prod database that is not possible for this downtime as we estimate it could take 24-48 hrs to do properly. Is there any way we can do this without using a bacpac? It is a bit frustrating as MsSQL allows below to do it:
ALTER DATABASE xxxxxx SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

ALTER DATABASE xxxxxx COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8

ALTER DATABASE xxxxxx SET MULTI_USER;

If anyone has anything - my only thought was somehow using replication in Azure if possible but don't know much about it as to whether to go down that path

The posted statements only change the database's default collation. It will not change the collation on any of the existing character-based columns nor their indexes.

Yes I understand I still must change a tables column collation but that can be done while the db is online. Unfortunately changing the db collation cannot from my knowledge be done in azure itself, only by modifying a bacpac is the only solution i see.

Also just like to add if the db setup is using a db collation of not ending in UTF8. You can still change column collation to use UTF8 and a varchar column can save UTF8 data but it needs an N in front of the string. If the db is setup using UTF8 then it can be saved without the N. This is important for our application. Also checking the syst.types column for varchar shows the collation of UTF8 or not at db level. So if i could update/insert varchar strings without an N and keep my old collation then i think i can do this.

As per MS Document

You cannot change or set the logical server collation on Azure SQL Database, but can configure each database's collations both for data and for the catalog. The catalog collation determines the collation for system metadata, such as object identifiers. Both collations can be specified independently when you create the database in the Azure portal, in T-SQL with CREATE DATABASE, in PowerShell with New-AzSqlDatabase.

The only way to change an existing database collation is by using the BACPAC file as workaround.  The ALTER DATABASE COLLATE statement you provided is not supported on Azure SQL Database.
To reduce the downtime you need to take copy of the database and change the collation for it and restore it and again rename it to previous, you can follow below approach given by @Mousa Janini as below:

Copy the database to a higher service tier on the same server.

Use SQLPackage to export the database to bacpac.
Change the collation by modifying the model.xml file.
Import the database again to a higher service tier, using SQLPackage and overriding the model.xml path.
Change the database name.

For detailed information please refer this document
